# Windows randomly downloads 1.5 Gb - how can I pinpoint the process responsible?

Tags: windows, windows-8, internet, process, monitoring

I often use a tool called 'BitMeter' to keep track of my computer's data usage (Windows 8). Very recently, I have checked the tool to find that my computer downloaded approximately 1.5 Gb of data. This has never happened in years previous, and now it has happened three or so times in the last week. When I look at the download history graph, it appears that this download happens all at once in a very short time period. I know that I personally am not responsible for this spike. I have scanned my computer with multiple anti-spyware programs without results. Does anyone know of a way to keep track of internet data usage by process? IE - does anyone know of a way to see if Mozilla is responsible, or Windows Updater, etc?

Comment: Does this happen at the same time each time it occurs?  Using something like Wireshark might be useful if so.

Comment: No, it doesn't - it happened once at 10:00am, once at 3:00pm, once at 4:00pm.

Comment: Windows Updates? A new service pack to install?

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as downloading 1.5Gb in a very short time. It should take a while. Is bitmeter showing the results of a bunch of small downloads from a session all at once when the session terminates?

Comment: The [built-in resource monitor](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-use-resource-monitor-windows-7) which might shed some light.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Windows updates doesn't account for the usage. By 'very short time period' I mean within an hour - and not spread out like you would expect it to be.

Comment: You need [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29). Which one i don't know but this [link](http://alternativeto.net/tag/firewall/) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) which I understand is quite like OSX's Little Snitch.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx). It's free and published by Microsoft, and displays established connections received / sent bytes.

However, being a very simple utility program, it doesn't support tracking the activity of each process. Still handy if you want to know which program is using your internet connection.

If you want a logging solution, [Netbalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) looks like a good candidate, although I haven't used it myself.